# Clear the stock or Clear out the stock

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> **Clear the stock**
>
> **Clear out the stock**

Which one is correct and formal?

I have searched in Google and got results for both.

Also Google Ngram shows more results for "clear the stock" than "clear out the stock".

**Stock** here in my example means "all the goods available at factory, which we want to despatch"

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*Out* intensifies the meaning of *clear* - i.e. it means "completely."  *Out* is associated with removal.

*Out*, *up*, *down* are often used like this to mean "completely" or "totally."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But stock here means all the available goods. So what should I use here? "Clear the stock" or "Clear out the stock". If the answer is "Clear out the stock", then why not the other? Could you please explain

Comment: Can anybody help on this subject?

Comment: I cannot cite a source for this, but to me "clear out" has a physical connotation, "He cleared out his desk" implies that the physical items in a physical desk located in physical space were removed. In accounting terminology, "to clear" means to set to zero. If I want to rid my stockroom of physical inventory, then a clearance sale to clear out my physical inventory seems idiomatic to me as a banker. If I want to turn inventory into money and reduce my investment in inventory to zero, then clearing the books of inventory seems idiomatic to me as a banker. The verb depends on point of view.